# Check scrolling with CSS

Tags: css, scroll

I am trying to create a pure 100% CSS (no jQuery) "Back to Top" button but I would like the button to show only if the visitor scrolls down the page.

Is it possible to check that with CSS somehow? So if visitor scrolled down a bit show the "Back to Top" button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Determine by Cursor Location

One way you could do this would be to only show the `.toTop` element when the user is hovering over the content of the page itself, well below the header, and navigation links:

```css
.toTop { opacity: 0; }
.toTop:hover, main:hover + .toTop { opacity: 1; }
```

You can see the effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/GFfbe/1/

#### Or, Slowly Uncover It

Alternatively, you could slowly uncover the `.toTop` link with another element. In the example below, I use the body's pseudo element `::before` to cover up the `.toTop` element, and slowly reveal it as the user scrolls:

```css
/* .toTop will appear in the left margin */
body {
    margin: 0 10em;
}

/* Positioned and sized to overlap .toTop */
body::before {
    content: "";
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 5em;
}

/* Positioned, so body::before goes behind it */
main {
    position: relative;
}

/* Attached to viewport at bottom left */
.toTop {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1em; left: 1em;
}
```

You can see this effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/GFfbe/2/

Comment: 1. "Back to top" appear even we don't need a scroll.  
2. If we scroll a little bit, we could see a half of "Back to top" button. http://jsfiddle.net/GFfbe/8/

Comment: Smart idea. Only negative i find with this trick is that it won't work with mobile users, like all the other `:hover` techniques . .

Comment: @JoE.: why won't it work with on mobile devices? `:hover` seems to enjoy universal support by mobile browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahover

Comment: @HassanBaig I think its because `hover` collides with `click` since phones can't `hover` like desktop users with a mouse cursor. So in a smartphone if you touch an image for example, the hover handler will trigger, but if you have a click handler it will trigger also. I think that was and is still the issue?