# Custom logo with link to homepage

Tags: css

I have a trouble to add custom logo with link to navbar if we scroll down

is class "dropdown-menu dropdown-inverse"

site: http://its-skin.upgates.com

CSS:

```
.secondlogo {
background-image: url(http://static.its-skin.upgates.com/m/m57daee4256187-sublogo.png);
width: 250px;
height: 54px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

here is the code full code :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav top-menu top-menu-categories">
    {else}
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-inverse" data-designer="d1-2-2-1">
    {/if}
        {foreach $tree as $category}
            <li class="ct_{$category['category_id']} lev-{$level}{if $category['active']} active{/if}{if count($category['childs'])} dropdown{if $level > 1} dropdown-submenu{/if}{/if}" data-target-category="{$category['target_category_id']}">
                <a href="{$category['url']}"{if $category["blank_yn"]} target="_blank"{/if} class="TopMenuLink">
                    {$category['name']}
                    {if (count($category['childs']))}
                        <i class="caret"></i>
                    {/if}
                </a>
                {if count($category['childs'])}
                    <button class="btn SubcategoriesLink"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
                {/if}
                {include #desktopMenu tree => $category['childs'], level => $level + 1, option => false, colsCount => ceil(count($category['childs'])/$itemsInCol)}
            </li>
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Where  exactly do you like to have the Image? Can you Name the Navigation item or provide a Screenshot? And should the Image Link to somewhere else than the Navigation item?

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply! https://postimg.org/image/8cimh5sab/
and image is in the css (.secondlogo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another list element at start of your ul which holds the link

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav top-menu top-menu-categories">

     <!-- New Element with class logolink -->      
      <li class="ct_29 lev-1 logolink">
       <a href="http://its-skin.upgates.com/" class="TopMenuLink">
         Link                   
       </a>
       </li>
       <li class="ct_29 lev-1" data-target-category="29">
       <a href="http://its-skin.upgates.com/krasa-it-s-skin" class="TopMenuLink">
       Krása It's Skin
       </a>
       </li>
                    ...
      </ul>
```

Then just use css to put your logo in front of it

```
.logolink {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/16x16/ff0000);
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px; /* Adjust to your logo size*/
}
```

Example:
[image]

In case you want just a clickable logo image without text, wrap it inside the hyperlink `<a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>` and forget about the background-image in css.

**EDIT:**

If you want a fade-in effect when a user scrolls your page have a look at these two excellent jquery libraries which provide this functionality.

- http://scrollmagic.io/
- http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/

Alternative you can fade in with some jquery code. Therefore hide the logo (element) by setting it´s opacity to 0, detect the viewport scrolling and fade it in at some point. Find a working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mwtebtw9/1/

Code taken from: http://www.ordinarycoder.com/jquery-fade-content-scroll/

Comment: Hi, thank you. My question is:is possible?  i need to show this logo if i scroll down

Comment: Hi thomas can you describe the wanted behavior with scoll down? Should the Logo stay on a fixed Position or only appear when you scoll down?

Comment: Yes, only appear if i scroll down

Comment: Hi Thomas I´ve edited my answer. Let me know if this is what you´re looking for. I assumed that you want to show the Logo without any other text. That´s why I kicked out the background-image css in the fiddle. Cheers, t-book

Comment: Thank you so much, i try this

Comment: Works, but i dont know how to implement jquery script to this system

Comment: which system do you use?

Comment: its a custom CMS - UPgates

Comment: If you have access to the CMS Code have a look if you can find the templates. If it´s written in MVC pattern you´ll find most likely a folder called views or templates. Have a look there. Otherwise you can just open another question on how to add jquery to UPgates.

Comment: check this: http://postimg.org/image/u9tgjmq6t/
and http://postimg.org/image/aczk8yt99/

Comment: and your question regarding your screenshots?

Comment: other solution without jquery , like  display: none; ?

Comment: please check the sceenshots now

Comment: The problem is you need to detect the User scolling. I´ve never read about a way doing this with pure css(3). Of course there are css3 transition effects but you need a way to fire them on a certain point. Here Javascript comes into play ...

Comment: maybe one solution I see is if you have some element which you can use with hover, you could hide/show the logo see this post `http://stackoverflow.com/a/21176266/1474777`

Comment: I dont understand what syntax is a solution in css , :hover?

Comment: You're Page has jquery already loaded! You just need to find a way to add the Little Code snippet (fiddle) I have postet above to your Page. Is there some kind of Documentation of the cms or Support?

Comment: Documents Unfortunely not founded

Comment: I contacted the tech support, and we can do this for cash :) an we said "its close source system"

Comment: Yes, i do this! now trouble if i scroll up the logo not hide :(